# Select mixed value from a column in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mixed

I am having registration table, in that student grades are `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12` and after sometimes client has changed the grade values to `Grades 1 - 3, Grades 4 - 6, Grades 7 - 12`

The MySql DB column has the Grades value of `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,Grades 1 - 3, Grades 4 - 6, Grades 7 -12.`

Now I am creating the report, so I need to filter the grades based on `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12` but I need to select the Grades `1` and also the record has `Grades 1 - 3`.

If I use the `SELECT * FROM registration WHERE Grades LIKE "%1%"` means I am also getting the Grades `1,10,12,Grades 1 - 3`

[image]

Any suggestions or help is appreciated.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a bit help.

Comment: If you have a situation where client can input anything they like then there can be no definitive solution..

Comment: Now you know why comma delinited lists in a column are a bad idea, they are a processing nightmare

Comment: @P.Salmon It is in select box. Fixed values. Thanks

Comment: DroidDev :) That actually makes it worse :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Please check the screenshot

Comment: Are you saying that the grades are not stored in a comma delimited list in a single column?

Comment: It's going to be tricky selecting where  grade =  2 and you have grade13 stored (or grade 1- 3 or grade1 -3)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, It is stored either from 1 to 12 or Grades 1 - 3, Grades 4 - 6, Grades 7 - 12

Comment: @P.Salmon It is not possible to select those mixed values?

Comment: It's possible of you have cast iron rules for grade formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple answer solves my problem,

`SELECT Grades FROM registration WHERE Grade ="1" OR Grade ="Grades 1 - 3"`

Based on the query from user, using if condition(in php) the Grades in the WHERE clause will be populated.

Comment: Does it? It seems you have to know all the possible formats when searching for grade 1 - that's not really what programming is about - what would happen if grade 1 - 6 appeared without your knowledge..When writing code you should make it as general as possible to capture all the known and as many of the unknowns you can imagine.

Comment: And trap any unimagined unknowns elsewhere so that you can finesse your code.

Comment: @P.Salmon As I already said it is select box which has fixed value currently `Grades 1 - 3`, `Grades 4 - 6`, `Grades 7 - 12`